# Is it possible to show DML that is locking some table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, locking

I already saw [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56615/how-to-determine-if-an-oracle-table-is-locked-or-not) how I can list my locked objects. Suppose I, using PL/SQL Developer(pink cylinder logo one), run `select * from someTable for update` and didn't commit nor rollback. Now using the query from the linked question, I was able to discover 'someTable'. I want to retrieve the full query. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

To see each session's currently running SQL (which supposedly holds the lock) you can join `v$session` with `v$sqltext`. I don't have anywhere to test this but something along these lines (using the answer you linked to as a starting point):

```
select
   c.owner,
   c.object_name,
   c.object_type,
   b.sid,
   b.serial#,
   b.status,
   b.osuser,
   b.machine,
   s.sql_text
from
   v$locked_object a ,
   v$session b,
   dba_objects c,
   v$sqltext s
where
   b.sid = a.session_id
and
   a.object_id = c.object_id
and s.address = b.sql_address and s.hash_value = b.sql_hash_value 
and s.piece = 1
;
```

This will retrieve the first "piece" of the SQL statement. If you need the complete statement, see for example [this link on "Ask Tom"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:497421739750).

Comment: You can see what session is holding the blocking lock, but not necessarily the actual sql statement.  The problem is that v$session only points to the most recent statement processed by that session.  It could very well be that the offending session issues multiple sql statements without a commit, and the statement that created the lock in question was not the most recent of those several statements.

Comment: Agree with Ed. You can look at V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY but even that can miss the offending statement.  The only way to find it is in a trace of the session, and even then it might be hard to find the SQL that caused the lock.  The good news is that it's usually obvious as a select for update runs for long enough to catch it.